# Copy apk files in a bash script

Tags: android, bash, adb

I tried the following script written by me.

```
#!/bin/bash
adb -s 015d2578a7280412 shell ls /data/app > apps.txt 
while read line
do
    apk=/data/app/$line
    adb -s 015d2578a7280412 pull $apk apk-nexus7-default
done < apps.txt
```

I got errors like:

```
' does not existdata/app/com.StudioOnMars.CSPortable-1.apk
' does not existdata/app/com.adobe.reader-1.apk
...
```

When I tried

`adb -s 015d2578a7280412 pull /data/app/com.adobe.reader-1.apk apk-nexus7-default`

It worked.

Any problem with the piece of scripts?

Comment: Try running your script in debug mode. `bash -x scriptname`

Comment: Your problem is that ADB assumes it will be talking to a Windows host, and inserts extraneous carriage returns in the output of `ls` which confuse your script.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Interesting point! How can I easily overcome this?

Comment: `adb -s 015d2578a7280412 shell ls /data/app | tr -d '\r'> apps.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue with `adb` - that even in linux it is using MSDOS style [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) characters - `CR+LF` (`'\r\n'`) instead of just `LF` (`'\n'`).

The easiest way to mitigate that is to remove `'\r'` from the `adb` output

```
adb -s 015d2578a7280412 shell ls /data/app | tr -d '\r'> apps.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
$ adb  -s 015d2578a7280412 pull /data/app/

pull: building file list...
pull: /data/app/some.apk -> ./some.apk
...
```